# Javascript problems with code, TypeError: comp1GameTitle is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

Welcome again,and again. I have a lot of errors,it's just joking with me.
The code is works here => https://jsfiddle.net/jh5tkfpp/ posted by a forum member (Sridhar). But in my local-webserver it's throwing `TypeError: comp1GameTitle is null` .

```js
var cGamePic = new Array("https://c6.staticflickr.com/9/8804/28522899701_efbaa953a7_n.jpg", "https://c5.staticflickr.com/7/6003/6004770804_692aecf57c_b.jpg", "https://c5.staticflickr.com/7/6006/6004652276_87ba0278a9_b.jpg", "https://c7.staticflickr.com/7/6139/6007896022_c7ac652043_b.jpg");
var cGameName = new Array("beach", "cycle1", "cycle2", "cycle3");
var randomItemContainer1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cGamePic.length); //container1

var randomItemContainer2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cGamePic.length); //container2

var comp1GameTitle = document.querySelector("#container1 h1"); //Heading from main container
var comp1GameImage = document.querySelector("#container1 img"); //Image from main container


var comp2GameTitle = document.querySelector("#container2 h1"); //Heading from main container
var comp2GameImage = document.querySelector("#container2 img"); //Image from main container


comp1GameTitle.innerHTML = cGameName[randomItemContainer1];
comp1GameImage.src = cGamePic[randomItemContainer1]; //Random image
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
 <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <title>Random_page</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="rnd.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container1" style="float:left; width:40%; margin:10px;">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <img src="" width='100%' height='100%' />
        </div>
        <div id="container2" style="float:left; width:40%; margin: 10px;">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <img src="" width='100%' height='100%' />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the code is working fine. It's showing the innerHtml & image as it is suppose to do

Answer (score 0):

It works in jsfiddle since they are executed onload. But you have put scripts in the `head`. So when they are executed DOM is not ready there is no element with id `container1`. So you can make changes as following snippet

```
<body>
//Rest of code
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rnd.js"></script>
</body>
```

else you can still keep `rnd.js` inside header tag but put all code in rnd.js inside  a [**window.onload**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) function